# I want to display images as well as text that retrieve from database

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I want to show or display image and text both from database using php 
when I display image form a database then it show image in that page at the same time when I echo some text in that no text is shown in the output page. 
I mean to say I want to show a employee image as well as it's data in a single page. I'm new in PHP So I do too much R&D on it. but didn't get the result.

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $dbname     = "dat-database";
    $password   = "";


    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $emp_id='';

    $sql = "select  * from emp_personaldetails where EMP_ID='1456'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
       echo $row['image'];
       $emp_id=$row['empid'];
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Employee id</td> <td><?php echo $emp_id; ?></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are images stored in the database?

Comment: `var_dump($emp_id);` - What does it say?

Comment: @rupesh i have answered to your question,plz check and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,this is working fine in my local system;

**Code:-**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "root";
    $dbname     = "dat-database";
    $password   = "";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $emp_id='';

    $sql = "select  * from emp_personaldetails where EMP_ID='1456'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
       $image=$row['image']; 
       $emp_id=$row['empid'];
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Employee id</td> <td><?php echo $emp_id; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Employee Image</td> <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image) .'" />';?></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently you changed the doctype of the whole resulting page to an image so no more content could be displayed:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

Assuming that your images are stored in base64 you could use something like the following:

```
$b64Src = "data:img/jpg;base64," . $row["img"];
echo '<img src="'.$b64Src.'" alt="" />';
```